# Задать имя файла при использование WriteXML

Tags: c#, xml

Доброе время суток,сообщество! Подскажите,как добавить переменную в путь при использование метода WriteXML ? Хочу чтобы было вида :
    string name = DateTime.Today.ToString();
    sRDataSet.WriteXml("C:/sanbak/name.xml");

Comment: `sRDataSet.WriteXml("C:/sanbak/" + name + ".xml");` ?

Comment: К сожалению нет, при данном формате происходит исключение,которое сообщает нам о том что : Данный формат пути не поддерживается,данный вариант это было первое что пришло в голову.

Comment: Приводите дату в корректный вид в том же `ToString` в приемлемый для вас формат

Comment: Показал в ответе как можно дату форматнуть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `WriteXML`, в принципе, не причем. Путь передается в виде строки, а в строках можно делать конкатенацию, в том числе с переменными:

```
string myValue = "Hello, world";
Console.WriteLine("Текст из переменно myValue: " + myValue);
```

Соответственно строка будет в вашем случае:

```
string name = DateTime.Today.ToString(); 
sRDataSet.WriteXml("C:/sanbak/" + name + ".xml");
```

Только не забудьте подформатировать дату в том виде, какой вас интересует. 
Потому, что в сыром виде, т.е. когда пишите `DateTime.Today.ToString();` или `DateTime.Now.ToString();` и т.д. - дата будет иметь вид `6/18/2016 5:07:03 PM/AM`. Как видим оно будет иметь слэши, а также двоеточия, которые недопустимы в имени файла. Из-за этого будут вываливаться ошибки, что *Данный формат пути не поддерживается*.

Значит нужно принудительно привести к корректному формату.

Например:

```
string name = DateTime.Today.ToString("d-MM-yyyy");
```

Чтоб был формат день-месяц-год

Или посложнее

```
string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH'h'mm'm'ss's'");
```

Выведет что-то типа: `19.06.2016 10h23m38s`

---

Какие форматы есть - можно смотреть прям на MSDN, к примеру

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx

Или [еще где](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: интересно, с когда добавляем форматирование всё работает,а если просто использовать ' DateTime.Today.ToString(); ' ругается на формат. Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @Madushko Потому что дата в сыром виде `6/18/2016 5:07:03 PM/AM`.  Т.е. будет иметь слэши, а также двоеточия, которые недопустимы в имени файла. Из-за этого будут вываливаться ошибки